# Flatten dictoinary of arbitrary depth

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, flatten

I receive from another script a dictionary containing various types, in particular other dictionaries or lists that might contain other dictionaries as values.

Now what I want to do is create a single flat dictionary. Keys might be present multiple times within the encapsulated dictionaries. For me the inner most key holds the newest information, so I think `dict.update` is the right routine to apply when digesting a 'inner' dict. By 'inner' dict I mean a dictionary withing some value of the outermost dictionary.

Now, I understand how to flatten a dictionary by 1 level. What I struggle with to to flatten it by arbitrarily many levels.

A simple example example of the type of dictionary I'm dealing with is:

```
d = {1: {6: {7: {2: {'a'}}}}, 2: 'b', 3: {4: {2: 'c'}}, 5: ['a', 'b', {1: 'a'}]}
```

My attempt works ok for a single level of depth:

```
dd = dict()
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        dd.update(v)
    elif isinstance(v, list):
        for el in v:
            if isinstance(el, dict):
                dd.update(el)
        dd[k] = [el for el in v if not isinstance(el, dict)]
    else:
        dd[k] = v
```

This gives me:

```
Out[56]:  {6: {7: {2: {'a'}}}, 2: 'b', 4: {2: 'c'}, 1: 'a', 5: ['a', 'b']}
```

What it should give is:

```
{2: 'a', 5: ['a', 'b']}
```

Note the value of the key `2`: `'c'` and not (as I get now) `'b'`. This should be because the inner-most value for the key `2` is `'c'` and not `'b'`.

I'm not just looking to get a functioning code (although this would allow me to continue working) but I'd like to understand how such a problem is tackled in python. I have to admit that I'm a little lost here...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `{2: 'c', 1: 'a', 5: ['a', 'b']}` your desired output? Should't `4` be present somewhere in it?

Comment: @Ajax1234 yes, this is the desired output! Actually it is correct that `4` is not present anymore, as the key `4` contains a `dict` with its content being imported on the top level. Not sure if I'm expressing myself clearly, so in principle there could be `4: {}` but that holds no information and can thus be removed.

Comment: Actually, have a look at this library: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html, and which operating system are you using?, because that will affect how you would install that library

Comment: @user904542 macOS or linux somethimes this somethimes that... thanks for the link, I'll have a look at this!

Comment: @user904542 but that's only for numpy arrays. I have a `dict` object holding all kind of objects, in particular `int`, `float`, `list`, `dict`, `tuple`, `boolean`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator and keep a counter to determine the depth:

```
d = {1: {6: {7: {2: {'a'}}}}, 2: 'b', 3: {4: {2: 'c'}}, 5: ['a', 'b', {1: 'a'}]}
def flatten(_d, _depth = 0):
  for a, b in _d.items():
     if isinstance(b, list):
       yield [a, [i for i in b if not isinstance(i, dict)], _depth]
       for c in b:
          if isinstance(c, dict):
             yield from flatten(c, _depth+1)
     elif isinstance(b, dict):
        yield from flatten(b, _depth+1)
     else:
        yield [a, b, _depth]

_result = {}
for a, b, c in flatten(d):
  if a not in _result:
     _result[a] = [b, c]
  else:
     if _result[a][-1] < c:
       _result[a] = [b, c]
print({a:b for a, [b, c] in _result.items()})
```

Output:

```
{2: {'a'}, 5: ['a', 'b'], 1: 'a'}
```

Comment: So I would directly overwrite `d` with `d = dict(flatten(d))`, right?! But here also, if you set `d = {1: {6: {7: {2: {'a'}}}}, 2: 'b', 3: {4: {2: 'c'}}, 5: ['a', 'b', {1: 'a'}]}` then the output dict has the pair `2: 'c'` but it should have the output pair `2: 'a'` as `'a'` is the inner-most value for the key `2`.

Comment: @TimC Please see my recent edit, as I just added a solution to reflect this.

Comment: wow, this looks complicated. Do I understand this correctly: you keep the depth as a parameter and then run again through the flattened `dict` and use the values with the highest depth, is that correct?!

Comment: @TimC Yes, precisely.

Comment: Many thanks for your willingness to help with this, by the way!

Comment: @TimC Glad to help!

Comment: Hm, the only thing now is the key `1`. It does not actually hold any information other than the the value for key `2`, so key `1` should not figure as it has no own value.

Comment: @TimC What about `1` appearing in `5: ['a', 'b', {1: 'a'}]`? Is it being ignored because `1` already occurred as a "parent" key?

Comment: ah you are right! Sorry! This is actually perfect! Thanks a lot. Not just for the code but also for explaining!

Comment: @TimC Ok, no problem!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct. But you have update the dict recursively for it to work on any number of levels

```
def flatten(d):
    dd = dict()
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            dd.update(flatten(v))
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for el in v:
                if isinstance(el, dict):
                    dd.update(flatten(el))
            dd[k] = [el for el in v if not isinstance(el, dict)]
        else:
            dd[k] = v

    return dd

d = {1: {2: {'a'}}, 2: 'b', 3: {4: {2: 'c'}}, 5: ['a', 'b', {1: 'a'}]}
print flatten(d)
# {2: 'c', 1: 'a', 5: ['a', 'b']}
```

Comment: Nice, this does actually not look that complicated! But does this always use the inner-most value for a key?

Comment: If I use `d = {1: {6: {7: {2: {'a'}}}}, 2: 'b', 3: {4: {2: 'c'}}, 5: ['a', 'b', {1: 'a'}]}` then the output dict has the pair `2: 'c'` but it should have the output pair `2: 'a'` as `'a'` is the inner-most value for the key `2`.

Comment: I updated to question to capture the 'depth' problem.